# How to make a single request with next js and generate metadata?

Tags: next.js

I have been testing Next.js App routes, and it's making two requests. It may seem obvious, but I'm struggling to find sufficient documentation to only make one request to fetch product information and pass it to both the page and generateMetadata function.

```js
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from "next"
import Product from "@/components/Product/product.component"

type Props = {
    params: { ean: string }
}

async function getProduct(ean: string) {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.API_URL + `/v1/products/${ean}`)
    return res.json()
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { ean } }: Props, parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
    const productData = getProduct(ean)

    const [product] = await Promise.all([productData])

    return {
        title: product.name,
    }
}

export default async function Page({ params: { ean } }: Props) {
    const productData = getProduct(ean)

    const [product] = await Promise.all([productData])

    return <Product product={product} />
}
```

I need to know if this is the best possible solution or if there is a better one

Comment: It does make the request twice but it shouldn't matter much because the responses are [cached](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating) so it should only hit your endpoint once. Also, you can actually use `const product = await getProduct(ean)` instead of that whole `Promise.all` that isn't doing you any favours since you're passing the promise inside an array and then destructuring the first element, making it unnecessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

> ...help you find accidentally impure code, Strict Mode calls some of your
> functions (only the ones that should be pure) twice in development.
> This includes...

You can read more about this here

[Fixing bugs found by double rendering in development](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development)

If you disable Strict Mode (not recommended), it should go away. In production mode it should also go away. To do a quick check, run `next build; next start`

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and searching I found this discussion:
https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/171ng7a/generatemetadata_and_the_server_component_calling/

✅ Solution: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#react-cache-function

Documentation of the `cache()` function: https://react.dev/reference/react/cache

Code suggestion using the same example given above:

```js
import { cache } from 'react';
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import Product from '@/components/Product/product.component';

type Props = {
  params: { ean: string };
};

const getProduct = cache(async (ean: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/v1/products/${ean}`);
  return res.json();
});

export const generateMetadata = async ({ params: { ean } }: Props): Promise<Metadata> => {
  const product = await getProduct(ean);

  return { title: product.name };
};

const Page = async ({ params: { ean } }: Props) => {
  const product = await getProduct(ean);

  return <Product product={product} />;
};

export default Page;
```

NOTE 1: Be aware that this `cache()` function is still being listed in the [Doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/cache) as experimental.

NOTE 2: Be careful not to use non-accessible parameters in the function that goes inside `cache()`, for example, avoid using objects like `props` or `params`, as apparently these parameters are used to generate the cache key, so it might be a good idea to try using primitive types like `string`.